# Can bounded operator concept extend from topological vector space to metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, computer-science, topological-vector-spaces, hash-function

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) says:

> In functional analysis and operator theory, a bounded linear operator
> is a linear transformation ${\displaystyle L:X\to Y}$ between
> topological vector spaces (TVSs) ${\displaystyle X}$ and
> ${\displaystyle Y}$ that maps bounded subsets of ${\displaystyle X}$
> to bounded subsets of ${\displaystyle Y.}$.
>
> If ${\displaystyle X}$ and ${\displaystyle Y}$ are normed vector
> spaces (a special type of TVS), then ${\displaystyle L}$ is bounded if
> and only if there exists some ${\displaystyle M>0}$ such that for all
> ${\displaystyle x\in X,}$
>
> $${\displaystyle \|Lx\|_{Y}\leq M\|x\|_{X}.}$$

Since [bounded subset concept exists in TVS and in metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Definition_in_a_metric_space), can  bounded mapping concept exist in metric space? For example,

Given metrics spaces $M_1 := (S_1, d_1)$ and $M_2 := (S_2, d_2)$, a mapping $f:M_1\to M_2$ is said to be bounded, if  $\exists M \geq 0$, so that $\forall x, y \in M_1$, $d_2(f(x), f(y)) \leq M \times d_1(x, y)$.

Is a hash function with the diffusion property (https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec21.html) an example of a non-bounded operator on a metric space:

> Diffusion (stronger than injection): if k1 ≠ k2, knowing h(k1) gives no information about h(k2). For example, if k2 is exactly the same as k1, except for one bit, then every bit in h(k2) should change with 1/2 probability compared to h(k1). Knowing the bits of h(k1) does not give any information about the bits of h(k2).

Thanks.

Comment: This is called a [Lipschitz map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)

Comment: @Didier thanks. I seem to remember something. Could you also see if a hash function with the diffusion property  is exactly an example of a non Lipschitz mapping?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have little to no background in both probability and cryptography, so I can't tell

Comment: If we define a metric on the set of bit sequences to be the number of bits that are different, the concept of diffusion can be a concept in metric space alone, can't it?

Comment: The thing is that this seems to involve a non-deterministic process (the "with probability $\frac{1}{2}$"). And I'm afraid that I'm not really qualified to investigate this in detail. What I can tell is that it seems to require that close but different points *can* (or *must*?) have very distant images. The question is then "do we control how distant these images can be (Lipschitz map) or not?", and I have no answer to that

Comment: However, the theory of Lipschitz maps has been investigated in depth and is a very well-known subject, and I'm sure that someone with a better background in cryptography / probability can answer your precise question in a few words

Comment: Just a remark: if you restrict to a finite numbers of bits, then the set of words $k$ is finite, then any function $f$ is automatically Lipschitz: $M = \max_{k_1\neq k_2}\frac{d(h(k_1),h(k_2))}{d(k_1,k_2)}$ gives a Lipschitz constant.