# How is the diffusion property of a hash function stronger than the injection property?

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, computer-science, hash-function

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec21.html says

> For a hash table to work well, we want the hash function to have two
> properties:
>
> Injection: for two keys k1 ≠ k2, the hash function should give
> different results h(k1) ≠ h(k2), with probability m-1/m.
>
> Diffusion (stronger than injection): if k1 ≠ k2, knowing h(k1) gives
> no information about h(k2). For example, if k2 is exactly the same as
> k1, except for one bit, then every bit in h(k2) should change with 1/2
> probability compared to h(k1). Knowing the bits of h(k1) does not give
> any information about the bits of h(k2).

Does "Diffusion (stronger than injection)" mean that if a hash function has the diffusion property, then it has the injection property?

If [the injection property is a consequence of the uniformity property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574874/is-the-injection-property-of-a-hash-function-a-consequence-of-the-uniformity-pro), then it is also a concept in probability theory, isn't it?

If [the diffusion property is a concept in the metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574869/can-bounded-operator-concept-extend-from-topological-vector-space-to-metric-spac), how can diffusion be comparable and imply the injection property described in probability theory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, yes.  Suppose $h(k_1)=h(k_2)$ holds with probability $1/2$.  Then knowing $h(k_1)$ gives you information about $h(k_2)$: there is a 1/2 chance that you can predict the value of $h(k_2)$.  However, neither of these two properties are defined in a precise, rigorous way, so it's not possible to give an absolute definitive "yes".